# How to customize Bootstrap's files to only get what's needed to make the carousel component work?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

I need to add the Bootstrap carousel component to my project, but I don't want to add all the baggage that comes with the framework.

I've tried to use [this link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/) to customize the Bootstrap files, but it does not work, even when everything is marked.

So, how should I proceed so I can add only what's necessary to make the carousel component work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use owl carousel 2 instead of using bootstrap's carousel

For using owl carousel please follow the https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/demos.html

And for customization, you can follow https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/2ejyz